# calculate the absolute area from a graph that also gets negative

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, integrate

I want to calculate the absolute area under the given graph. What now happens is that it just integrates the line f. This line also gets negative. I am integrating from -5 to 5.

How can I adjust the function so it will give the absolute value?

edit:
Something else I would like to know is how to calculate the area only where f(x) >0? Is there an option to do a double integral easily?

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = arange(-5,5.001,0.00001)
f = cos(4*x+1)**2 *(6 - 0.5* x**2)





print(trapz(f,x))
plt.plot([-5,5],[0,0])
plt.plot(x,f)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `abs(cos(4*x+1)**2 * (6 - 0.5*x**2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`numpy.abs(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html?highlight=abs#numpy.absolute) to calculate the element-wise absolute value for the array of values.

So we can calculate the values for `f` with:

```
f_abs = np.abs(f)
print(trapz(f_abs,x))
```

This will then calculate an approximation of the area, and thus consider the area under the *x*-axis to be positive as well.

If you want to ignore the negative parts, you can set negative values to `0` with [**`numpy.clip(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
print(trapz(f.clip(min=0),x))
```

Comment: i have another question. How do i calculate the integral between f and y. only the positive parts? i need to calculate the area of the graph between f>0

Comment: @Marco: you can clip the list of values, instead of using abs. So `f.clip(min=0)` will set all negative values to zero.